# How to add caffe to anaconda on windows?

Tags: python, import, caffe

I'm trying to use **Caffe** in **Anaconda3** on windows, but when I try to import caffe in iPython, it shows this error:

> ImportError: No module named caffe

I tried to add a new system variable named **PYTHONPATH** which looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Hadi\Anaconda3;C:\Projects\caffe\python\caffe;C:\Projects\caffe\python
```

It still shows the same error. I would appreciate if anyone mentioned what am I missing here?

Comment: How did you try to install `cafe`? Did you follow these steps: https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package

Comment: Yes I tried `conda install caffe` but it didn't recognize the package

Comment: My last suggestion was incorrect, I'm sorry, I didn't realize `caffe` is not officially supported on Windows. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a quick install option, on their [homepage](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) is a link to [Windows see the Windows branch led by Guillaume Dumont](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) which uses Visual Studio and CMake. There's also a discussion about it [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/15).

Comment: Thanks @downshift. I'm trying to build caffe again from scratch. I unistalled Anaconda 2 and installed Anaconda 3. I hope it works.

Comment: Ok I hope it works too

Comment: This one is working: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6569#issuecomment-432491851

Answer (score 13, accepted):

REM Create a new conda environment to install Caffe
REM You can use python 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7

```
conda create -n caffe python=3.7
```

REM activate the environment
REM Depending on your conda version you may have to use activate caffe

```
conda activate caffe
```

REM add the anaconda channel to resolve all dependencies

```
conda config --add channels anaconda
```

REM Install caffe with cuda support or install caffe-cpu if you do not want CUDA support

```
conda install caffe -c willyd
```

Answer taken from here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6569#issuecomment-432491851

Comment: `conda install caffe -c willyd` raises error: `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`

Comment: Haven't tried this in a while. It used to work before. Maybe version incompatibility issue of anaconda or something.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked for me. The incompatility had been solved.

Answer (score 1):

caffe doesn't have support for windows as it have for others. After trying many things, i am able to import caffe. The best solution i find is the git link https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe .

Create a virtual environment in Anaconda, python = 3.7 and then follow the instructions.

You would have to make changes CommonSettings.props as mentioned in the documentation for CUDA and cuDNN if you would be using it with CPU only.

clone repository to the location and copy caffe folder to .\anaconda3\envs\env_caffe\Lib\site-packages location as stated in the documentation .

and finally un the following commands from elevated command prompt:

conda install --yes numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-image pip
pip install protobuf.

Read the instruction carefully and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
{conda create -n caffe python=x.x}    
{conda activate caffe}     
{conda config --add channels anaconda}     
{conda install caffe -c willyd}
```

Change the version of python, it should work then.
Answer taken from here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6569#issuecomment-432491851